# Can I use GET request instead of PUT to create resources?

Tags: jax-rs

*Can I use GET request instead of PUT to create resources?*

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can, but the only way to pass data in a GET request is by the URL itself.  It would be pretty bad design.

Comment: Down voters should provide some reason too. This seems like a reasonable  doubt for a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  But it will surprise some people, and probably earn you some verbal abuse.

Comment: And go against all the best practises. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) is worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

GET requests don't support bodies.  So you can create stuff, but not using user input.

Comment: Surprisingly, a lot of server side frameworks will allow a GET body, and some client side libraries will also generate a body if you ask nicely.  But it does violate the specification and my own sense of all that is right with the world when GET is used this way.